# Is it possible to see basic usage data for this site?

Tags: feature-request

Specifically about the geographic locations users visit from and perhaps peak times.

I'd be really interested to see the most active countries and times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analytics data from sources such as Google Analytics (or other 3rd party ones) are not provided to the general public, as far as I am aware anyway. However there are various sources of public information that is visible.

Probably the Quantcast figures for the site are enough for what you're after:

https://www.quantcast.com/ux.stackexchange.com#!geo

> The volume of traffic originating from individual countries in a 30 day period. Indexes are calculated by comparing the percentage of a site's traffic from a given country to the pattern of all Internet traffic measured by Quantcast - e.g, an index of 500 indicates that the site gets five times as much of its traffic from the given country than the average Internet site
>
> `COUNTRY       UNIQUES (COOKIES)   UNIQUES %   UNIQUES INDEX   IMPRESSIONS %   IMPRESSIONS INDEX`
>
> `US            103,167             34.45       59               34.25          82`
>
> `UK            26,800              8.95        224              11.00          389`
>
> `India         26,294              8.78        566              7.88           462`
>
> `Canada        14,291              4.77        160              5.13           180`
>
> `Australia     9,574               3.20        225              2.96           212`
>
> `Germany       9,102               3.04        140              3.78           271`

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised the US is so dominant in the numbers. I think the site has more international feel : /